To use hugging face model, what are shards (same as checkpoint)? Do I need all?
I want to use this for a zero-shot QA model: https://huggingface.co/nvidia/NVLM-D-72B/tree/main
When I download it using the following, it starts downloading 46 shards. There are 46 bin files in the link above. Do I need them all? What else do I do to use this model for zero-shot QA?
path = "nvidia/NVLM-D-72B" model = AutoModel.from_pretrained( path, torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16, low_cpu_mem_usage=True, use_flash_attn=False, trust_remote_code=True).eval()

I tried running the code, it was too large on disk space. I have capacity to do it but I wonder if it is even required?

Shards are basically sharded checkpoints that are beneficial to use when the model is too large to fit into memory in one piece, check out https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/v0.19.0/en/usage_guides/big_modeling#sharded-checkpoints. In other words, they are the trained model parameters and you do need all of them to use the model.
If you look into https://huggingface.co/nvidia/NVLM-D-72B/blob/main/model.safetensors.index.json you will see that it maps each sublayer of the 80 main layers to the file its found in.
With regards to the memory needed you can check out this tool to estimate memory usage: https://hf-accelerate-model-memory-usage.hf.space/. You will find that running the model in default the float32 precision requires about 300 GB. If you want to reduce that you should look into quantization, which will bring this down quite a lot, check out https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/usage_guides/quantization.
If you really do have the local hardware to make this work I would recommend using pipelines for inference, see https://huggingface.co/tasks/question-answering#inference. You first load the model with a quantization_config, then hand the loaded model to the pipeline, afterwards you can use the model as shown here.
